# SQL Query to get only 1 instance of a record where one to many relationship exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ive got an SQL Query trying to get 1 record back when a 1 to many relationship exists.

```
SELECT     dbo.BlogEntries.ID AS blog_entries_id, dbo.BlogEntries.BlogTitle, dbo.BlogEntries.BlogEntry, dbo.BlogEntries.BlogName, 
                      dbo.BlogEntries.DateCreated AS blog_entries_datecreated, dbo.BlogEntries.inActive AS blog_entries_in_active, 
                      dbo.BlogEntries.HtmlMetaDescription AS blog_entries_html_meta_description, dbo.BlogEntries.HtmlMetaKeywords AS blog_entries_html_meta_keywords, 
                      dbo.BlogEntries.image1, dbo.BlogEntries.image2, dbo.BlogEntries.image3, dbo.BlogEntries.formSelector, dbo.BlogEntries.image1Alignment, 
                      dbo.BlogEntries.image2Alignment, dbo.BlogEntries.image3Alignment, dbo.BlogEntries.blogEntryDisplayName, dbo.BlogEntries.published AS blog_entries_published, 
                      dbo.BlogEntries.entered_by, dbo.BlogEntries.dateApproved, dbo.BlogEntries.approved_by, dbo.blog_entry_tracking.id AS blog_entry_tracking_id, 
                      dbo.blog_entry_tracking.blog, dbo.blog_entry_tracking.blog_entry, dbo.BlogCategories.ID, dbo.BlogCategories.BlogCategoryName, 
                      dbo.BlogCategories.BlogCategoryComments, dbo.BlogCategories.DateCreated, dbo.BlogCategories.BlogCategoryTitle, dbo.BlogCategories.BlogCategoryTemplate, 
                      dbo.BlogCategories.inActive, dbo.BlogCategories.HtmlMetaDescription, dbo.BlogCategories.HtmlMetaKeywords, dbo.BlogCategories.entry_sort_order, 
                      dbo.BlogCategories.per_page, dbo.BlogCategories.shorten_page_content, dbo.BlogCategories.BlogCategoryDisplayName, dbo.BlogCategories.published, 
                      dbo.BlogCategories.blogParent
FROM         dbo.BlogEntries LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.blog_entry_tracking ON dbo.BlogEntries.ID = dbo.blog_entry_tracking.blog_entry LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.BlogCategories ON dbo.blog_entry_tracking.blog = dbo.BlogCategories.ID
```

i have some records assigned to 2 different blogcategories, and when i query everything it returns duplicate records.

How do i only return 1 instance of a blog?

Comment: I removed my answer because I misread your post. Pieter is right. SELECT DISTINCT is what you want.

Comment: Does `BlogEntries` hold individual instances of a blog? (The table name makes it sound like it holds individual posts on a blog.) As long as you include blog category details (such as blog category title) in your `select` clause, `select distinct` will not remove duplicate entries for the same blog under different categories, since your query returns all categories being tracked. Do you want to retrieve only the details for the first category for a blog (and how would you decide which category is first)?

Comment: Did you figure it out?  It's good to post what you did for future readers, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT  blog_entries_id = be.Id
    ,   be.BlogTitle
    ,   be.BlogEntry
    ,   be.BlogName
    ,   blog_entries_datecreated = be.DateCreated
    ,   blog_entries_in_active = be.inActive
    ,   blog_entries_html_meta_description = be.HtmlMetaDescription
    ,   blog_entries_html_meta_keywords = be.HtmlMetaKeywords
    ,   be.image1
    ,   be.image2
    ,   be.image3
    ,   be.formSelector
    ,   be.image1Alignment
    ,   be.image2Alignment
    ,   be.image3Alignment
    ,   be.blogEntryDisplayName
    ,   blog_entries_published = be.published
    ,   be.entered_by
    ,   be.dateApproved
    ,   be.approved_by
    ,   blog_entry_tracking_id = bet.Id
    ,   bet.blog
    ,   bet.blog_entry
    ,   bc2.Id
    ,   bc2.BlogCategoryName
    ,   bc2.BlogCategoryComments
    ,   bc2.DateCreated
    ,   bc2.BlogCategoryTitle
    ,   bc2.BlogCategoryTemplate
    ,   bc2.inActive
    ,   bc2.HtmlMetaDescription
    ,   bc2.HtmlMetaKeywords
    ,   bc2.entry_sort_order
    ,   bc2.per_page
    ,   bc2.shorten_page_content
    ,   bc2.BlogCategoryDisplayName
    ,   bc2.published
    ,   bc2.blogParent
FROM dbo.BlogEntries be
LEFT JOIN dbo.blog_entry_tracking bet ON be.Id = bet.blog_entry
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM dbo.BlogCategories bc
    WHERE bet.blog = bc.Id
) bc2
```

Also, I would like to mention that in this case, using of aliases in the column names decreases the size of your query and makes it more convenient for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

if you just need one record back, you can use

SELECT TOP 1 dbo.BlogEntries.ID AS blog_entries_id, dbo.Bl.... (same as you have now).

it is more efficient than SELECT DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Northwind Example.

It will return only 1 row in the Order Detail table for each Order.

```
Use Northwind
GO

Select COUNT(*) from dbo.Orders
select COUNT(*) from dbo.[Order Details] 


select * from dbo.Orders ord
join
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY UnitPrice DESC) AS "MyRowID" , * from dbo.[Order Details] innerOD) derived1
on ord.OrderID = derived1.OrderID
Where
derived1.MyRowID = 1
Order by ord.OrderID
```